# Sulu 1.6: Live Preview of custom template not working

Tags: sulu

After reading http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/cookbook/live-preview.html and also crosschecking the [example.html.twig](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-standard/blob/develop/src/Client/Bundle/WebsiteBundle/Resources/themes/default/templates/example.html.twig) I still can not find out why the love preview is not working in my template.

My Template hierarchy (using the theme bundle):

1. bs_homepage.html.twig, extends:
2. main.html.twig, extends:
3. master.html.twig

In a nutshell the structure is like:

**bs_homepage.html.twig** (just sets some parameters and calls the main template)

```
 {% extends "DWBNFrontendBundle:main:main.html.twig" %}
```

**main.html.twig**

```
 {% block content %}
     [...]
     <div id="content" class="container" vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Content">
          [...]
          <div class="row">
                [...]
                <section class="col-sm-{{ mainCollSize }} main-content" id="content" vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Content">
                {% if content.title %}
                     <h1 property="title">{{ content.title }}</h1>
                {% endif %}

                [...]
          </div>
     </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

**master.html.twig**

```
  [...]
  <body>
      <!-- content -->
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      <!-- /content -->

      [...]
  </block>
```

And the xml definitions:

**bs_homepage.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<template xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template-1.1.xsd">

    <key>bs_homepage</key>

    <view>DWBNFrontendBundle:templates:bs_homepage</view>
    <controller>SuluWebsiteBundle:Default:index</controller>
    <cacheLifetime>2400</cacheLifetime>

    <meta>
        <title lang="de">Startseite</title>
        <title lang="en">Homepage</title>
    </meta>

    <properties>

        <xi:include href="fragments/content-core.xml" xpointer="xmlns(sulu=http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template) xpointer(/sulu:template/sulu:properties/sulu:section[@name='highlight'])"/> 
        [...]
    </properties>
</template>
```

**fragments/content-core.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<template xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template-1.1.xsd">

    <properties>

        <section name="highlight">
            <properties>
                <property name="title" type="text_line" mandatory="true">
                    <params>
                        <param name="headline" value="true"/>
                    </params>

                    <tag name="sulu.rlp.part"/>
                </property>
                [...]
            </properties>
        </section>
    </properties>
</template>
```

But if I change the title, nothing happens in the preview window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: In your question I can't see if your property is named "title" in your xml.

But I think the problem is when it's initially rendered, the `h1` html node does not exists.
Therefore a update to this node can't happen at all.

Try to add something like this:

```
    <div property="title">
        {% if content.title %}
            <h1>{{ content.title }}</h1>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Comment: I added the xml structure, adding the wrapper div did unfortunately not do the trick.

Comment: Actually it did! I had an additional template error, because not all variables are set in the preview update ajax request.